# el.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded() scrolls too far up

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

[el.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoViewIfNeeded) scrolls to `el` if it's not inside of the visible browser area. In general it works fine but I'm having problems with using it with a fixed header.

I made an example snippet: (The method doesn't work in Firefox, so neither does the demo) https://jsfiddle.net/ahugp8bq/1/

In the beginning all three colored divs are displayed below the fixed header. But if you click "second" and then "first", the beginning of `#first` will be behind the header, which I don't want.

The problem seems to be that the position of `#otherContainer` (its `padding-top`) is pretty much ignored when scrolling up.

Comment: This seems to be depending on the direction you are moving in - basically, it will try to position the entire element inside the viewport and stops when its completed, so when you scroll down it will stop once the bottom pixel hits the bottom of the viewport, and when you scroll up it will be when the top pixel hits the viewport top. But to be honest, you could easily just do `document.body.scrollTop = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + document.body.scrollTop` to scroll to the desired position - supported by all browsers and consistent.

Comment: @somethinghere Same problem with `document.body.scrollTop = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + document.body.scrollTop` (https://jsfiddle.net/ahugp8bq/2/). You are right with your analsis, that's also the documented behaviour (and what I wanted). The problem is that it doesn't respect where its container is positioned.

Comment: Oh shit... Simple. Use `document.body.scrollTop = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + document.body.scrollTop - header.clientHeight` to align them correctly :) (get the header using `var header = document.getElementById('container')`). Also, your example fiddle seems very cumbersome as it defines the same code for each.

Comment: "Also, your example fiddle seems very cumbersome as it defines the same code for each". Yeah, it's just meant as a simple example :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is quite simple if you use the consistent and supported `getBoundingClientRect().top + body.scrollTop` way - all you now have to do is reduce the header from it, so just get it and calculate its height.

```js
var header = document.getElementById('container')
var clicks = document.querySelectorAll('#container li');
var content = document.querySelectorAll('#otherContainer > div');

// Turn the clicks HTML NodeList into an array so we can easily foreach
Array.prototype.slice.call(clicks).forEach(function(element, index){
  element.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Set the scroll to the top of the element (top + scroll) minus the headers height
    document.body.scrollTop = content[index].getBoundingClientRect().top + document.body.scrollTop - header.clientHeight;
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: fixed;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#otherContainer {
  padding-top: 60px
}

#first, #second, #third {
  height: 500px
}

#first {
  background: red
}

#second {
  background: green
}

#third {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <ul>
      <li id="jumpToFirst">first</li>
      <li id="jumpToSecond">second</li>
      <li id="jumpToThird">third</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="otherContainer">
  <div id="first"></div>
  <div id="second"></div>
  <div id="third"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not the `el.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(false)` behaviour though. `el.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded` only scrolls if `el` isn't in the viewport already and it scrolls either to the top or bottom, depending on which is closer. Of course it's possible to implement that logic myself, but since `el.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded` generally works pretty well, I'm thinking that maybe just a small tweak is needed (e.g. in the CSS).